# How to show the convexity of this set

Tags: convex-optimization

Is the set, $S=\{\bf x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{e^{x_i}}{1+e^{x_i}}=1 \}$, a convex set?

Comment: For $n=2$, the set $S$ is equal to $S=\{\bf x \in \mathbb{R}^2: x_1+x_2=0\}$ which is convex. But I am not able to show it in higher dimension.

Comment: Nonlinear equations are almost always not convex, so much so that you should never even bother to hope they are. There really are no exceptions to this rule in practice; the only actual exceptions are manufactured, like $x^2=0$.

Comment: Your edit changes nothing. It's still a nonlinear equality constraint. There is no reason whatsoever for you to have hope this could be convex.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a convex set. I have the following counterexample for $n=2$ (calculated by hand, so it might be wrong):

Take $a=(\ln(\frac{1}{4}),\ln(\frac{2}{5}))$,$b=(\ln(\frac{2}{5}), \ln(\frac{1}{4}))$. This gives us $\frac{1}{2}(a+b) = (\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{10}),\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{10}))$

We have $a,b \in S$ but $\frac{1}{2}(a+b) \notin S$

Comment: I made a mistake in the question having $1-e^{x_i}$ in the denominator, but the correct one is  $1+e^{x_i}$, which I edited. Thank you for you answer which made me understand my mistake in writing the question

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[e%5Ex%2F%281-e%5Ex%29%20%2B%20e%5Ey%2F%281-e%5Ey%29%20%3D%3D%201%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%2C%7By%2C-1%2C1%7D) should help. It is always a good idea to plot. Note : $1$-dimensional convex sets are subsets of lines. You don't expect something having to do with exponentials to be a line segment (a priori it could have been, but your first guess should be no).

Comment: Dear Silvia, I don't know what do you mean by plotting it? Do you mean plotting $S$ set?.

Comment: @Sedi : It'd be nice if you could type my name correctly, but whatever (my first name is Patrick by the way, not Silva). What I meant is to go on Wolfram Alpha using my link and typing 

Plot[e^x/(1+e^x) + e^y/(1+e^y) == 1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]

this instead (I just changed the signs). You can type 

Plot[e^x/(1+e^x) + e^y/(1+e^y) + e^z/(1+e^z) == 1,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},{z,-1,1}]

too and see that your conjecture is true when $n=2$ but not for $n > 2$.

Comment: @Sedi : I tried plotting on WolframAlpha and for some reason it can't do the 3d plot, I don't know why. But Mathematica can definitely do it, if you have that (or any other plotting software).

Comment: @ Dear Patrick, I am sorry for the mistake of spelling your surname. I tried to plot in Matlab. It seems it's not convex.

Answer (score 1):

(Because the question changed ( $\frac{e^x}{1-e^x}$ became $\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$), i decided to write another answer)

It is still not convex. Your calculations for $n=2$ are correct, but e.g. for $n=3$ it is not correct, here is another counterexample (again, calculated by hand):

Take $a=(\ln(\frac{1}{2}),\ln(\frac{1}{5}),0)$,$b=(\ln(\frac{1}{5}), \ln(\frac{1}{2}),0)$. This gives us $\frac{1}{2}(a+b) = (\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{10}),\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{1}{10}),0)$

We have $a,b \in S$ but $\frac{1}{2}(a+b) \notin S$

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also find in $R^3$ if we choose point along any axis it will be a counter example. But what if the domain of vector $x$ will be restricted to be only in any of the 1/8 possible portion in $R^3$?

Comment: @Sedi : I suggest you plot it again and see for yourself!